# Python script runs another python script with variables

Tags: python

I have a script to grab files in a directory -

```
import os
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
hours = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 7)
delta = hours.timestamp()
PATH = '/opt/folder/folder/folder'
with os.scandir(PATH) as dir_contents:
     for entry in dir_contents:
        info = entry.stat()
        if info.st_mtime > delta:
            file = entry.name
            print(entry.name)
```

I want to loop through my list of files and run each 'file=entry.name' through this other script

```
otherscript.py file -c configfile
```

but how do I do that?  Is there a way to put this at the bottom of a script?

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `subprocess` within the `for loop` as ```subprocess.run(f"otherscript.py {file} -c configfile", shell=True, check=True)``` Remember to `import subprocess`

Comment: What about importing this other script and using arg parser?

Comment: Your both awesome.. import subprocess worked great!